# Enabling iCloud on AIR for iOS

Tags: ios, air

I'm developing iOS app on Adobe AIR(flash), and I want to use iCloud KeyValue function (using ANE).

How do I enable the iCloud function on AIR?

I assume that app.xml is how this is done, but do not know for sure.

Comment: My question is "where should I write entitlements for iCloud."

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this.

```
<Entitlements>
<![CDATA[
<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix).com.hoge.hugaApp</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
<string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix).com.hoge.hugaApp</string>
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
<array>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix).com.hoge.hugaApp</string>
</array>
]]>
```

I write like this from XCode Project's hugaApp.entitlement which is auto generated file.
And then I replaced $(TeamIdentifierPrefix) and $(AppIdentifierPrefix) to real value.

Thank you answering to me!

Comment: so, have you made an icloud native extension? anything you want to share there? :)

Answer (score 2):

Adobe AIR does not support natively the iCloud  (iCloud is supported natively by the iOS SDK).

In order to be able to use iCloud you need to use Native extensions using xCode and ObjC.
I may be wrong but I could not find any existing iCloud native extensions for AIR, just at a google check.

Anyway you can check this links:

http://extensionsforair.com/native-extensions/ios/

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html